# OASIS "Selective" Unbound module error for an internal module

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I try to compile a small OCaml [4.03.0+flambda] project using Oasis. I have four modules, three declared in Modules field and one using InternalModules. My _oasis configuration file is [there](https://github.com/yannham/mechaml/blob/master/_oasis).

The internal module is named Infix, and contains a submodule Option that gathers some useful infix operators to deal with option types. In the current github version of the code, available [here](https://github.com/yannham/mechaml/tree/master/src), everything work fine and I am able to build the project. Anyway, if I add the line "open Infix.Option" in the source file agent.ml so that it now looks like

```
[..LICENSE..]
open Lwt 
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix
open Infix.Option

type http_status_code = Cohttp.Code.status_code
type http_headers = Cohttp.Header.t
[..]
```

and I get the following error

```
+ /home/yann/.opam/4.03.0+flambda/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -c -g -annot -bin-annot -package cohttp -package cohttp.lwt -package lambdasoup -package lwt -package uri -I src -o src/agent.cmo src/agent.ml
File "src/agent.ml", line 23, characters 5-17:
Error: Unbound module Infix.Option
```

which is unexpected, especially because my current source file page.ml performs the same open and uses Infix.Open operators without any problem or error. I wonder what's happening and why agent.ml and page.ml are being treated differently by oasis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lwt` has an `Infix` module, which shadow your `Infix` module. Just reverse the order of opens.

Note that opening `Lwt` is often considered not very good style. If you want to use lwt's infix operator, you should open `Lwt.Infix` instead.